# How to make a tab click go directly to the next text field in a browser?

Tags: html, browser, navigation

Is there a way to make a tab click go directly the the next text field (input type text) in any browser? On my site, it goes to the next element, which is a link in my case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you need to override onclick method - that's javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `tabindex` attribute of your inputs to integers so the values increase sequentially in the order you want them to be focused in.

Answer (score 0):

Make a javascript file that checks for a keyCharCode for tab it is 9. A whole list can be found below.

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

```
function checkTab
{
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
          if (charCode == 9) 
          {  
             (Put your change form action in here)
          }
}
```

Something along those lines will work anyway

The key checker code works for certain, I've already used it as a form validator. But I'm afraid I dont know how to do the form changing off the top of my head.